# Pandas: Replace column values to empty if not present in pre-defined list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list, `X`, that contains a set of legal values for a column. Say, I have column `A`. I want to replace (set to empty string) elements in `df['A']` if their value is not in X. How can I do that efficiently in Pandas?

I know there is `isin()`, but that just checks if the values are present and returns a Series of True/False.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [standard Pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) here:

```
df.loc[~df.A.isin(X), 'A'] = ''
```

`~df.A.isin(X)` - will revert the boolean Series returned by [df.A.isin(X)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) (i.e. `False` -> `True` and `True` -> `False` )

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with apply:

```
import pandas as pd

x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = {'foo':['a', 'a', 'q', 'p']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df_new = df['foo'].apply(lambda i: i if i in x else '')
```