# Replace a column value if it not found data-frame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to python. Here I have following dataframe column,

```
  Predict
   100
   200
   2100
   2200
   51200
     0
   3600
```

Now I have the following 
array data

```
cols = [100,156,160,162,200,256,262,2200,2600,2900,3600,4600]
```

Now, Here I am trying to replace it with `0` if it is  not in the predict.

So result will be like

```
predict
 100
 200
 0
2200
0
3600
```

Now I tried

```
compare_df[~compare_df.isin(cols)] = 0
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
```

Can any one help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Replace column values to empty if not present in pre-defined list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001754/pandas-replace-column-values-to-empty-if-not-present-in-pre-defined-list)

Answer (score 1):

You have to working with `Series` instead of one column `DataFrame` by selecting with column name and `loc` for replace values of `Predict`:

```
compare_df.loc[~compare_df['Predict'].isin(cols), 'Predict'] = 0
```

If remove `loc` with column name it set all rows to `0` by mask (if exist):

```
compare_df[~compare_df['Predict'].isin(cols)] = 0
```

If use altarative with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) also select column `Predict`:

```
compare_df['Predict'] = np.where(compare_df['Predict'].isin(cols),compare_df['Predict'], 0)
```

But here working also:

```
compare_df['Predict'] = np.where(compare_df.isin(cols),compare_df, 0)
```

EDIT:

For compare need same types in column and in list, e.g. numeric or objects (obviously strings).

So is necessary for both strings values:

```
cols = [str(x) for x in cols]
compare_df.loc[~compare_df['Predict'].isin(cols), 'Predict'] = 0
```

Or for both numeric:

```
compare_df['Predict'] = compare_df['Predict'].astype(float)
compare_df.loc[~compare_df['Predict'].isin(cols), 'Predict'] = 0
```

If not working casting to floats by `.astype(float)`:

```
compare_df['Predict'] = pd.to_numeric(compare_df['Predict'], errors='coerce')
compare_df.loc[~compare_df['Predict'].astype(float).isin(cols), 'Predict'] = 0
```

Comment: Here everything is getting in 0 even if it is present

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - What is `print (compare_df['Predict'].dtype)` ?

Comment: It should only if that column value is not present in that array then only otherwise shuould have the column value only

Comment: Its is giving me object

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - It means you compare strings with integers with list.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - so possible solution is convert `cols` valus to strings before my solution - `cols = [str(x) for x in cols]`

Comment: What should  I do to changes this ? I mean cols should be an array of num

Answer (score 0):

This is [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).
it is better than `np.where` because you only have to do the assignment of 0 when the value is not present in cols.

```
new_df=df.where(df.isin(cols),0)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   Predict
0      100
1      200
2        0
3     2200
4        0
5        0
6     3600
```

If there are more than 1 col:

```
new_df=df.copy()
new_df['Predict']=df['Predict'].where(df['Predict'].isin(cols),0)
print(new_df)
   Predict
0      100
1      200
2        0
3     2200
4        0
5        0
6     3600
```

---

if they have different type:

```
new_df=df.copy()
new_df['Predict']=new_df['Predict'].astype(str) #this or the commented line depending on the type of cols and df ['Predict']
#new_df['predict']=new_df['Predict'].astype(int)
new_df['Predict']=df['Predict'].where(df['Predict'].isin(cols),0)
print(new_df)
```